# Joint PMF calculate probability

Tags: probability

2 fair die are rolled. Find joint pmf of X and Y if X is the value on the first die, and Y is the larger of the two values.

I don't understand why $P(2,2)...P(6,6)$ is $\frac{2}{36},\frac{3}{36}, ..., \frac{6}{36}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the first roll is $4$ and the largest is $4$ is the probability that the first is $4$ times the probability that the second is $\le 4$.

The probability the first is $4$ is $1/6$. The probability the second is $\le 4$ is $4/6$. Multiply.

Alternately, note that there are $36$ equally likely outcomes. Now list and  count the "favourables." They are $(4,1)$, $(4,2)$, $(4,3)$, and $(4,4)$, a total of $4$. Thus the probability is $\frac{4}{36}$.